# Python 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d

Tags: python, utf-8

I am trying to run the following python script:

```
#! python
import textmining
import glob

tdm = textmining.TermDocumentMatrix()

files = glob.glob("C:/Users/farre/Desktop/matrix/blurbs/*")
print(files)
for f in files:
  content = open(f).read()
  content = content.replace('\n', ' ')
  tdm.add_doc(content)
tdm.write_csv('matrix.csv', cutoff=1)
```

But I am getting an error

```
File "matrix.py", line 13, in <module>
   content = open(f).read()
File "C:\Users\farre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 688: character maps to <undefined>
```

I have tried a few things I seen on here but nothing has worked, I tried using `io.open(filename,encoding="utf8")` but I got:

```
File "matrix.py", line 11, in <module>
    content = io.open(f, encoding="utf8").read()
File "C:\Users\farre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 310: invalid start byte
```

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: What do those files contain? You could try opening them in *binary* mode, or if you don't care about the "special" chars, use `open`'s `errors=ignore` argument.

Comment: The file is being opened with the wrong encoding. Try `open(f, encoding='utf-8')`.

Comment: The files just contain plain text, I have just tried using `errors=ignore` and now I am getting an error on  the line `tdm.write_csv('matrix.csv', cutoff=1)`, the error is `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Comment: Try `open(f, encoding='cp1252')`; `b'\x94'` seems to be a double-quote of some kind, perhaps MS "smart quote".

Comment: If that text-mining library really prefers to work with `bytes` rather than `str`, then give it `bytes`: `content = open(f, 'rb').read()`. You'll also have to change the string literals in the subsequent line (use `b'\n'` and `b' '`).

Comment: MarkRansom and @snakecharmerb, how come you are both suggesting exactly the codecs that the OP has shown not to work? Is there a hidden edit history or something? (I'm curious, not ranting.)

Comment: @lenz could very well be an invisible edit, I don't remember seeing the `utf8` part. Usually the encoding is either the native one or UTF-8, and since the error message read `cp1252` I suggested the other. This makes it a mystery now of figuring out the correct code page.

Comment: @lenz my bad, I think I tried 0x9d with cp1252, it didn't work, then my eye must have slipped down to the utf-8 traceback, saw 0x94, assumed I'd misread earlier.  Sorry for the noise.